# sqlcontext.read.json produces a DataFrame with values from a directory in its path

Tags: scala, apache-spark

when reading json files into a DataFrame, this way:

```
val frame = sqlContext.read.json("path/ts=100/somefile.json")
```

in the DataFrame I receive, the ts values are all equal "100", even though there are different "ts" values in the file.

the weird thing is that if i use : `sqlContext.read.json("path/ts=100")`
I get all files into the frame, and the "ts" value is not overridden.
any idea how to work through it?

examples:

values in data frame:

**ts : 100**

values in json file:

{**"ts" : "5002342004"**}

Thanks.

Comment: It would be good if you explain with sample data. When you say "ts values are not overridden" what does it mean?

Comment: added, 
the ts value is determined by the directory **name** ts=xxx instead of the actual value inside the files.

Comment: @royashcenazi I am not completely sure, but `/ts=100/` looks like a _partition_ folder, and usually that mean that folder contains objects whose `ts` **field** is equals to `100`. Are you completely sure such file contains records with values different that `100` ?

Comment: yes, in my case it is a ts of a round hour (the directory name) and inside there are files with ts values that are different from the directory name.
it seems like spark deduces in its own i want to value from the directory name - and override the values inside the file

Comment: Looks like your json file has ts values with different than the file suggests.